# How to prevent a panel of appearing out of screen?

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I have a form that contain a datagridview. Whenever a user click on a row, a small panel appear just under the row and display some buttons. Everything is working as expected with the code below :

```
private void dataGridView1_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {

      rowSelected = e.RowIndex;
      columnSelected = e.ColumnIndex;

      if (e.RowIndex == -1) return;

      var cellRectangle = dataGridView1.PointToScreen(
      dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, false).Location);
      panel_EditButtons.Location = new Point(cellRectangle.X + 50, cellRectangle.Y);

      panel_EditButtons.Show();

    }
```

Could some one please tell me how to prevent the panel from appearing out of screen when the user click on a row and there is no sufficient space to display the panel ? Look at the two images i attached :

Normal view (When there is enough space to display the panel, the panel appear correctly)

[image]

When i click on the right side of the row (and there is no enough space to display the panel, the panel appear out of screen)
[image]

Could some one please tell me How can i show the full panel even when I click on the right side of the row and there is no enough space so the panel location is limited to screen width ?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I'm aware of, would be to reset the coordinates.

```
if (panel_EditButtons.Location.X + panel_EditButtons.Size.X > width)
    panel_EditButtons.Location = new Point(width - panel_EditButtons.Size.X, panel_EditButtons.Location.Y);
// same with Y
```

Keep in mind that my code is merely pseudo-code and that it probably won't work by simply copy-pasting.